# Markdown to plain text in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, markdown, bluecloth

I'm currently using BlueCloth to process Markdown in Ruby and show it as HTML, but in one location I need it as plain text (without some of the Markdown). Is there a way to achieve that?

Is there a markdown-to-plain-text method? Is there an html-to-plain-text method that I could feel the result of BlueCloth?

Answer (score 12):

RedCarpet gem has a [Redcarpet::Render::StripDown](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/blob/master/lib/redcarpet/render_strip.rb) renderer which "turns Markdown into plaintext".

Copy and modify it to suit your needs.

Or use it like this:

```
require 'redcarpet'
require 'redcarpet/render_strip'    
Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::StripDown).render(markdown)
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting HTML to plain text with Ruby is [not a problem](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#M000355), but of course you'll lose all markup. If you only want to get rid of *some* of the Markdown syntax, it probably won't yield the result you're looking for.

The bottom line is that unrendered Markdown is intended to be used **as** plain text, therefore *converting* it to plain text doesn't really make sense. All Ruby implementations that I have seen follow the same interface, which does not offer a way to strip syntax (only including `to_html`, and `text`, which returns the original Markdown text).

Comment: I'm fine with some of the markup, like lists; but for example, links are hard to read for non-technical people.

Comment: Line-wrapping, links (should be made into [1] references and added to the bottom), headers, white-spacing between elements, etc. can all be made better.

Answer (score -3):

It's not ruby, but one of the formats Pandoc now writes is 'plain'.  Here's some arbitrary markdown:

```
# My Great Work

## First Section

Here we discuss my difficulties with [Markdown](http://wikipedia.org/Markdown)

## Second Section

We begin with a quote:

> We hold these truths to be self-evident ...

then some code:

    #! /usr/bin/bash

That's *all*.
```

(Not sure how to turn off the syntax highlighting!) Here's the associated 'plain':

```
My Great Work
=============

First Section
-------------

Here we discuss my difficulties with Markdown

Second Section
--------------

We begin with a quote:

  We hold these truths to be self-evident ...

then some code:

    #! /usr/bin/bash

That's all.
```

You can get an idea what it does with the different elements it parses out of documents from the definition of `plainify` in pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Markdown.hs in the Github repository; there is also a [tutorial](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) that shows how easy it is to modify the behavior.